# bigchainDB vagrant tutorial failed provisioning

Tags: vagrant, blockchain, bigchaindb

I have tried this official bigchainDB tutorial, running with vagrant.
https://docs.bigchaindb.com/projects/server/en/v1.3.0/appendices/run-with-vagrant.html

Every time I hit the command `vagrant up`, it came out with this error below :

```
==> config-node: Configuring cache buckets...
==> config-node: Running provisioner: hosts...
==> bdb-node-01: Updating hosts on: bdb-node-01
==> config-node: Configuring cache buckets...
==> config-node: Running provisioner: shell...
    config-node: Running: inline script
    config-node: Operation Sytem: ubuntu
    config-node: Version: 16.04
    config-node: Dependencies already installed:[ ansible ]
==> config-node: Configuring cache buckets...
==> config-node: Running provisioner: shell...
    config-node: Running: inline script
    config-node: 
    config-node: PLAY [all] *********************************************************************
    config-node: 
    config-node: TASK [Gathering Facts] *********************************************************
    config-node: fatal: [bdb-node-01]: UNREACHABLE! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: Permission denied (publickey).\r\n", "unreachable": true}
    config-node:    to retry, use: --limit @/bigchaindb/configuration/bdb-deploy.retry
    config-node: 
    config-node: PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
    config-node: bdb-node-01                : ok=0    changed=0    unreachable=1    failed=0   
The SSH command responded with a non-zero exit status. Vagrant
assumes that this means the command failed. The output for this command
should be in the log above. Please read the output to determine what
went wrong.
```

does anyone have same issue?

Comment: Bug fixed : https://github.com/bigchaindb/bigchaindb/issues/2012

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like ansible is not able to log into bdb-node-01. Can you verify if the directory from which you are running **vagrant up** has:

> /path/to/vagrant/directory/.vagrant/machines/bdb-node-01/virtualbox/private_key

Can you also tell me the contents of:

> /path/to/repo/bigchaindb/pkg/configuration/hosts

I think if I have more information, I will be able to help you out more.

You can also file a ticket on our [github](https://github.com/bigchaindb/bigchaindb/issues) and we can work on it.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Yes, it has a private_key under `.vagrant/machines/bdb-node-01/virtualbox` directory.

Comment: As for the `pkg/configuration/hosts` directory, it has `all` file and the content of all file, its `bdb-node-01 ansible_user=ubuntu`.

Comment: I will also open a ticket for sharing of knowledge :)

Comment: Thanks. I will check it out.

Comment: This has been fixed [here](https://github.com/bigchaindb/bigchaindb/pull/2029). You can follow the discussion on our [GitHub](https://github.com/bigchaindb/bigchaindb/issues/2012) as well. I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you so very much and it worked with no error!!